# Did Sakura surpass Tsunade?

Tags: naruto

Judging from the war, Sakura's role was far less important compared to Tsunade. It looked like Tsunade was more capable of handling the war. Likewise Naruto and Sasuke have shown they surpassed all the other legends. Yes, at the end Sakura did help out, but her skills did not show something new or greater than Tsunade.
Is it safe to say the strongest female character in the Naruto series - after Kaguya - is Tsunade?

Comment: In terms of raw strength? Battle prowess? Overall skill? Comparing one shinobi to another is like comparing apples to oranges, or comparing someone such as [Kankurou](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kankur%C5%8D) to [Temari](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Temari). Even a head-to-head fight between Sakura and Tsunade could go in very different ways.

Comment: Comparing as sensei and student perspective. Like sasuke &  orichimaru and naruto & jiraya.

Comment: How would you say someone surpassed someone else or not? By seeing their ability in battle in comparison with the other person. So far, we haven't seen anything great from Sakura which Tsunade can't do. infact she never will get chance to show it (spoiler)

Comment: She got all the chance during the last battle tough. We saw kakashi showing some good skills, but sakura... Even earlier in the great battle none were shown [Spoiler]. So in comparison with that I feel like Sakura never surpassed Tsunade. Meanwhile naruto and sasuke manage to pull it off.

Comment: @Sarenya Regarding your last question, I would say there are a few females in the running for strongest female after Kaguya. Sakura, Tsunade, Mei, Konan, Chiyo, Kushina, and Mito should be considered. Based on what we know, I would argue that Kushina is stronger than Tsunade and Konan probably is too.

Comment: @krikara I strongly agree with you Kushina is much stronger then Tsunade and Konan.